# Как экранировать символ в python импорте?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сделать такой импорт:

```
from ..catalog-1.catalog import module
```

(Проблема в "-")

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/399583/293202

Comment: Это круто! Но в проекте уже так было, там до этого sys.path.append использовался. Как прикажете быть?

Comment: Или это вообще невозможно?

Comment: Никак. Либо переименовать папку, либо через sys.path.append как раньше.

Comment: Во сюрприз. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну еще есть вариант символьную ссылку на папку сделать, чтобы она виделась под именем без дефиса. Но это платформозависимое решение, и не все файловые системы такое поддерживают.

Comment: Верно, это не вариант. Придется переименовать.